# Call AJAX onkeyup event trigger. Use timer and abort to improve performance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am relatively new to AJAX and javascript and I am using ajax to generate search suggestions using an onkeyup event. I am trying to use a timer to regulate the number of ajax requests, and the abort function to improve performance. I never used these two functions before and I am unsure if they are set up correctly. I was wondering if someone can take a look and let me know if I am on the right track with these functions? Many thanks in advance.

```
            var ajaxReq = null;  
        $(".prod-name-input").keyup(function(){
            searchword = $(this).val();
            //alert(searchword);
            if((searchword.length) > 3) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = setTimeout(function(){
                    if (ajaxReq != null) ajaxReq.abort();
                    var ajaxReq =  $.ajax({
                                        url: "invoice-get-data.php?searchword=" + searchword,
                                        dataType: "html",
                                        success: function(data){
                                           $(".smart-suggestions").html(data);
                                        }
                                    });
                }, 350);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to have a look on the excellent article of Ben Alman on throttling / debouncing : http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/ .

What you want to achieve is a debouncing, so with Ben Alman's plugin, you can use :

```
var ajaxReq = null;  

$(".prod-name-input").keyup($.debounce(350, function(){
    searchword = $(this).val();

    if((searchword.length) > 3) {
        if (ajaxReq != null) ajaxReq.abort();
        ajaxReq =  $.ajax({
            url: "invoice-get-data.php?searchword=" + searchword,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data){
                $(".smart-suggestions").html(data);
             }
        });
    }
}));
```

---

**EDIT :**

In fact, it was a debouncing and not a throttling in your case.

I have added a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/2AFp3/ .

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can you please explain why this method is a better alternative to mine?

Comment: That's nearly the same as you, but I see many advantages : 1. We have a more precise control over the timing, 2. No more to have to deal explicitely with `setTimeout` and variable scope (this is encapsulated), 3. I think it is clearer and simpler to add...

Comment: +1, Thanks for the edit and the explanation :) this works well;)

Comment: I chose you're solution over mine, because it seems to be slightly faster, the only downside is having to use an additional plugin, however, this shouldn't be a deal breaker ;)